# Unable to create fragment module project in liferay developer studio

Tags: liferay

when i select module fragment project i got this in maven environment and liferay dxp 7.3 version
(error:Please set a valid liferay portal runtime, you can initBundle or modify 'liferayHome' property to make it point to an existing runtime)

Comment: would you consider using Liferay Workspace (thus, gradle), or is Maven mandatory?

Comment: i have created workspace with maven

Comment: Liferay workspace implies gradle though. It's different from eclipse's workspace (but lives well within it)